# A limit with floor

Tags: calculus, limits

I try to compute this limit (but without success). Any help will be welcome
Let $p$ be an integer $\ge 2$ and $q>1, 0\le \varepsilon<1$ be reals.

$$\lim_{\substack{n\in\mathbb N\\n\to+\infty}}\frac{\sum\limits_{h=1}^{\left[\frac{n}p\right]}(n+\varepsilon-hp)q^{(h-1)p}}{q^n}$$

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The numerator is a geometric sum and a sum of the form
$$
\sum_{0 \le k \le n} k z^k = z\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}
$$
The floor should not make much trouble, you can squeeze between one less and the argument (or just round up).

**Edit:** Expanding on the floor, which is troublesome for OP:

The sum in the denominator is of the following form, with constant $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
$$
\sum_{1 \le h \le \lfloor n / p \rfloor} 
    (\alpha + \beta h) \left(q^p\right)^{h - 1}
  = \sum_{0 \le h \le \lfloor n / p \rfloor - 1} 
       (\alpha + \beta h) \left(q^p\right)^h
$$
Substitute $\lfloor n / p \rfloor \mapsto m$, the resulting sum is easy to evaluate:
\begin{align}
\sum_{0 \le h \le m - 1} (\alpha + \beta h) z^h
  &= \alpha \frac{1 - z^m}{1 - z}
       + \beta z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1 - z^m}{1 - z} \\
  &= \alpha \frac{z^m - 1}{z - 1}
       + \beta \frac{z^m ((m - 1) z - m) + z}{(z - 1)^2}      
\end{align}
Now as
$$
\frac{n}{p} - 1 < \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p} \right\rfloor \le \frac{n}{p}
$$
and your sum is either an increasing or decreasing function of $m$, the correct value is near enough for your limit-taking purposes to the sum's expression evaluated at $m = n / p$ instead of the correct value $\lfloor n / p \rfloor$ (squeeze between $n / p - 1$ and $n / p$ if need be).

Comment: For me, the floor is actually a problem....

Comment: I use your notations: Let $f(\alpha,\beta,m,z)=\alpha\frac{z^m-1}{z-1}+b\frac{z^m((m-1)z-m)+z)}{(z-1)^2}$. My sum is $f(n+\varepsilon,-p, \left[\frac np\right],q^p)$. I obtain $f(n+\varepsilon,\frac np,q^p)\sim\frac{\varepsilon(q^p-1)+pq^p}{q^{2p}-2q^p+1}q^n$ and $f(n+\varepsilon,\frac np-1,q^p)\sim\frac{\varepsilon(q^p-1)+2pq^p-p}{q^{3p}-2q^{2p}+q^p}q^n$. So I do not know how to conclude.

Comment: @joaopa, it looks like your last result tells all: your $f()$ is the numerator, divide by $q^n$ to get the limit.

Comment: But the two limits are different. So I could not conclude

Comment: @joaopa, you are right. I was counting on the effect to get swamped by other dependecies on $n$. It looks like the limit doesn't exist (the expression oscilates between the values you give).